# Load parent component when loading children component selector (without hierarchy URL)?

Tags: angular, router, angular7, router-outlet

I want to load parent component when loading children component using selector.

Example:

comp-parent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'comp-parent',
  template: `
        <p>parent works</p>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `,
  styleUrls: ['./comp-parent.css']
  })
export class ComponentParent { 
    protected foo: string;
}
```

comp-children.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'comp-children',
  template: "<p>Children works</p>",
  styleUrls: ['./comp-children.css']
  })
export class ComponentChildren extends ComponentParent { }
```

routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: ComponentParent,
  children: [{
    path: '',
    component: ComponentChildren
  }]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ComponentRoutingModule {}
```

component-foo-bar.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-foo-bar',
  templateUrl: "<comp-children>",
  styleUrls: ['./component-bar.css']
  })
export class ComponentFooBar { }
```

In `ComponentBar` I would expect that `comp-children` will be `comp-parent` with `comp-children` included, but only `comp-children` template is loaded.

How to load children component using selector with parent loaded, when used in other component?

Comment: are you saying that the html you posted for the parent doesnt show? i find that hard to believe as thats what you need to do

Comment: I think it works on page routing, i.e. in state /app/components/ then It would work. I want to make it work outside of application state, only using selector.